# jwt.verify() returns jwt expired when the expiration is 24h

Tags: javascript, jwt

I used [jwt](https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken#readme) to create a token:

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const token = jwt.sign({
filePath: "path/to/file"
}, 'secretKey', {
expiresIn: "24h"
});
try {
  console.log(token)
  var decoded = jwt.verify(token, 'secretKey');
} catch(err) {
 console.log(err)
}
```

jwt.header:

```
{
  "alg": "HS256",
  "typ": "JWT"
}
```

payload:

```
{
  "filePath": "path",
  "iat": 1557833831,
  "exp": 1557920231
}
```

When I test the snippet code mentioned above in my real app, I got an error message:

```
jwt expired
```

Using the [jwt debugger](https://jwt.io/#debugger), the token is valid and should expire after 24h.
The error returned by `verify()` which checks the expiration. How jwt checks the expiration? or it does not check it?

Comment: What about if you try with an other value of `expiresIn` ? Like `5000` instead of the `24h`?

Comment: Are you fine with just a general explanation for expiring tokens? Or it has to be library specific for you?

Comment: Its a browser refresh issue. once I refresh the browser, issue resolves. Buts its not the expected behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So since the question is, how does jwt check the expiration date, it depends on basically on some properties that may be implemented according to the [JWT RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519#section-4.1.4)

One would be `exp`. In case a token expires before the current datetime, then the JWT cannot be processed

> The "exp" (expiration time) claim identifies the expiration time on
> or after which the JWT MUST NOT be accepted for processing.  The
> processing of the "exp" claim requires that the current date/time
> MUST be before the expiration date/time listed in the "exp" claim.

> Implementers MAY provide for some small leeway, usually no more than
> a few minutes, to account for clock skew.  Its value MUST be a number
> containing a NumericDate value.  Use of this claim is OPTIONAL.

Another one to note would be the `iat`, which stands for *issued at*

> The "iat" (issued at) claim identifies the time at which the JWT was
> issued.  This claim can be used to determine the age of the JWT.  Its
> value MUST be a number containing a NumericDate value.  Use of this
> claim is OPTIONAL.

A final one that could be used for time verfication, as far as I am aware of would be, `nbf`, standing for *not before*

> The "nbf" (not before) claim identifies the time before which the JWT
> MUST NOT be accepted for processing.  The processing of the "nbf"
> claim requires that the current date/time MUST be after or equal to
> the not-before date/time listed in the "nbf" claim.  Implementers MAY
> provide for some small leeway, usually no more than a few minutes, to
> account for clock skew.  Its value MUST be a number containing a
> NumericDate value.  Use of this claim is OPTIONAL.

Now, for the code at hand, I don't see anything which is of, having following setup, this works perfectly fine for me

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

const token = jwt.sign( {
  hello: 'world'   
}, 'myverysecretkey', {
    expiresIn: '24h'
});

try {
    const verify = jwt.verify( token, 'myverysecretkey' );
    console.log( verify );
} catch (err) {
    console.error( err );
}
```

which would output

```
Object {hello: "world", iat: 1557840459, exp: 1557926859}
```

This can be validated on the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/1oy681lp5l) link

Comment: Thank you very much for this explication. I know that the code works well, however when I call the same url using the generated token returned jwt expired and normally it lasts 24h. That's why I don't understand how this error was thrown. Because the iat does not reach the exp.

Comment: @Slim Maybe somewhere you send an old token? I am not really aware what might have gone wrong in your "real" app